# Searching array in PHP

Tags: php, forms, search, multidimensional-array, search-engine

I am developing a FAQ (Frequently Asked Question) PHP script and I want to implement a way for users to search the FAQs. This is a small script so I have the categories and FAQs in an array as shown below:

```
$qa = array();
$qa['Getting Started'] = array(array('What is 1+1?', '2'), array('What is the square root of 16?', 'The square root is 4'));
$qa['Installation'] = array(array('What is 2+2?', '4'), array('What is the square root of 64?', 'The square root is 8'));
```

Now, what I want to do is take a search query from a form (using a GET request) and search this array for that search query. I was wondering how I might go about doing this? Would I have to parse the search query first so that the array can be searched? Would I be able to use the `array_search()` function for this or would I have to write my own code to iterate through the array? I was also wondering if the FAQs are better to be stored using a different method (XML, SQL, etc) to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a database for the questions something like:

```
id int not null auto increment primary_key,
question text not null,
answer text not null
```

Then I would do a where like query:

```
...
WHERE question LIKE '%questionsearchvalue%'
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll just use a MySQL database for this instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this thread and especially read the comments of all the users. you might get what you needed.

http://greengaloshes.cc/2007/04/recursive-multidimensional-array-search-in-php/

Answer (score -1):

You can use an another approach to solve it. Echo all the FAQ and then use jquery highlight plugin to search in html.

[Here is the link](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)

Comment: The problem with that is the questions are listed categorically (meaning only the FAQs for the selected category are shown).

Comment: show the main category, hide sub categories and content then expand according to your search result.